# SCN issue for older Oracle versions

Tags: oracle

I am new to this, therefore need some help:

We are using PeopleTools 8.48, Peoplesoft Enterprise 8.8 for CRM application. We have database of Oracle v10.2.0.5.0. Recently, because of SCN issue, we have been asked to apply the following patches- Patch 14121009 + patch 16619894 DBPSU (July 2013 PSU).

my question- are these patches compatible with the PeopleSoft/PeopleTool and Oracle versions? Do we need to make any upgrades in parallel?

Comment: You will probably have to open a ticket with Oracle Support to even get access to a patch for that old of an Oracle release.  But *usually* Oracle patches should not affect application software.

Answer (score 0):

Product certifications typically include version numbers up to the patchset version, the 4th number (10.2.0.**5**), which will not change by installing those patches.

I applied those patches last year at a customer and we had no issues at all, although they were using a custom application, not Peoplesoft.